# Why my flex 4.6 cannot recognize JSON.parse

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, swc

I am using the following code to parse a JSON URL:

```
var result:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.parse(event.result)
```

But it cannot recognize `JSON.parse`, I am using as3corelib.swc (9.3 version).

What is the issue? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to parse JSON in Flex.

One is to use [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib).  In that case, you need to change your code to

```
var result:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(event.result)
```

The other way (if you're targeting Flash Player 11+) is to use the built-in [JSON class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) (in the default package):

```
var result:Object = JSON.parse(event.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON API is provided by flash player, not by Flex SDK. Seems, you're using 10 version or older. Try installing newer version (11+) of flash player plugin and **playerglobal.swc** for your SDK. Put it to **SDK/frameworks/libs/player/$player_version**. Also you should point flash player version by setting `<target-player>` content in **SDK/frameworks/flex-config.xml** file.